# Openni_launch Quickstart tutorial slightly out of date

Tags: openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As is requested at the top of the tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/QuickStart), I'd like to report that Step 4 is a little out of date.

The dynamic_reconfigure gui has been changed to rqt_reconfigure's rqt_reconfigure (rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure). The "driver" tag in the left column of the GUI is where the tutorial picks up again.

Other than that, the tutorial was very helpful =)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197021/openni_launch-quickstart-tutorial-slightly-out-of-date/) by [Jackson Carter](https://answers.ros.org/users/20733/jackson-carter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the wiki is a community effort, you are welcome (and encouraged) to fix anything you find that is incorrect.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1